# Java swing, Changing java swing windows but blank screen appearing. When running each program separate , each works fine

Tags: java, swing

I am Designing a login screen and a main menu screen in Java using java swing. The problem i am getting is when the login is correct,  I get a blank java swing window when i already designed the main menu.

I just started learning Java so i am not quite knowledgeable on it.

I am designing the frame by myself, meaning i am not using the GUI Interface, all buttons and Text boxes are done manually.

This is login code.

```
package loginapp;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Login_App extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


JFrame frame = new JFrame("Mo Garage Login");
        //frame setup
        frame.setSize(500, 600);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        //Label and Text boxes

        JLabel usernamelbl = new JLabel("Username");
        usernamelbl.setBounds(100,100, 100,20);
        frame.add(usernamelbl);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);


        JLabel passwordlbl = new JLabel("Password");
        passwordlbl.setBounds(100,200,100,20);
        frame.add(passwordlbl);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);



        JTextField username = new JTextField();
        username.setBounds(200,100,100,20);
        frame.add(username);
        frame.setLayout(null);//using no layout managers 
        frame.setVisible(true);



        JPasswordField pass = new JPasswordField();
        pass.setBounds(200,200,100,20);
        frame.add(pass);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);



        //Buttons

        JButton log=new JButton("Login");
        log.setBounds(200,500,100,40);

        frame.add(log);
        frame.setLayout(null);//using no layout managers  
        frame.setVisible(true);
        //login button action
        log.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent arg0) {

            String uname=username.getText();
            String passwd=pass.getText();

            if (uname.equals("") && passwd.equals(""))
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Login Successfull");

                MainMenu mainmenu =new MainMenu();

                mainmenu.setVisible(true);

                frame.setVisible(false);

            }
            else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Incorrect Credentials");
            }


        }
        }
    );

        JButton clear=new JButton("Clear");
        clear.setBounds(50,500,100,40);

        frame.add(clear);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        //clear button action

        clear.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                username.setText("");
                pass.setText("");

            }
        }
        );

    }


}
```

This is my main menu code.

```
package loginapp;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;


public class MainMenu extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame= new JFrame("Main Menu");
    frame.setSize(500,600);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    JButton client= new JButton("Add new Client");
    client.setBounds(200,100,120,30);
    frame.add(client);
    frame.setLayout(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    JButton Mod= new JButton("Update Database");
    Mod.setBounds(190,200,140,30);
    frame.add(Mod);
    frame.setLayout(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    JButton info= new JButton("Information");
    info.setBounds(200,300,120,30);
    frame.add(info);
    frame.setLayout(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    JButton exit= new JButton("Quit");
    exit.setBounds(200,400,120,30);
    frame.add(exit);
    frame.setLayout(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

I tried different methods but i could not find it. Help please.
Thank you.

Comment: They might not display because you arent adding your components to your *contentPane()*

Comment: 1) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556). 2) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) ..

Comment: .. 3) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently. 4) **`frame.setVisible(true);` is called multiple times. It should be done once, after all components have been added, and after `pack()` has been called.**

Answer (score 0):

In your `Login_App` class, in the `actionPerformed()` method, you call the constructor of class `MainMenu` like so...

```
MainMenu mainmenu =new MainMenu();
```

However, class `MainMenu` does not have a constructor - at least not in the code you posted. You build the GUI in method `main()` of class `MainMenu`. So I would suggest the easiest solution - based on the code you posted - would be to change the code in method `actionPerformed()` of class `Login_App`. Replace the line shown above with...

```
MainMenu.main(new String[]{});
```

Answer (score 0):

while every one comments was absolutely right and helpful but your proplem wasn't in any !! **your proplem is in adding the `Component`'s to `MainMenu` object**  .
so in short , copy the hole code of the `main` of the `MainMenu` and put it in another method let's call it go `public void go()` and replace the line :-

```
JFrame frame= new JFrame("Main Menu");
```

with

```
this.setTitle("MainMenue");
```

and replace any refrence of the object `frame` with the keyword `this` .

Answer (score -2):

Try calling the method revalidate() at the beginning of actionPerformed for your login. It reloads the frame.

Comment: *"It reloads the frame."* No, it revalidates them (just like the method name suggests).